# side slide menu not creating push effect in ipad and phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, menu, jquery-animate

I am using the following side slide menu for my project :-

http://www.mywork.com.au/blog/demos/facebook-sidebar-menu/

I've changed the left slide-in to right slide-in. It works very well for me on the desktop but in ipad and phone the page wrapper has a lagging-behind/scrolling effect. It seems like that the page wrapper scrolls from right to the left under the side menu container after the menu has appeared.

I've tried using "fast", "slow" and other properties of animate but don't seem to figure out what exactly needs to be done.

```
$(".m-menu").toggle(function() {
        $('#mobile-menu-bg').animate(
            { right: '0', speed: '1500' },
            1500
            //{ duration: 500, queue: false },
        );
        $('#page-wrapper').animate(
            { 'margin-left': '-80%', speed: '1000' },
            1000
            //{ duration: 500, queue: false }
        );
    }, function() {
        $('#mobile-menu-bg').animate(
            { right: '-80%' }
            //{ duration: 500, queue: false }
        );
        $('#page-wrapper').animate(
            { 'margin-left': '0' }
            //{ duration: 500, queue: false }
        );
    }
);
```

Please help

Comment: your link is not working... can you provide a fiddle???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anitakcx/7Bjn9/

Comment: this is a modified version - its working on desktop, have also used twitter bootstrap